# Bicycle pump connector thread size

Tags: mechanical-engineering, threads

Does anybody know what the thread size is on a bicycle pump connector, such as this one?

[image]

**Note**: I'm not talking about the female end that goes on the valve stem on the bike (that's a Schrader valve thread), I'm talking about the male end that connects with the pump. It looks almost like an M5, but doesn't quite fit in an M5 female connector.

I have spent quite a bit of time googling the question, but have drawn a blank so far.

Comment: As it is usually in soft metal, the UNC or Whitworth spring to mind...

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's the same thread as a Presta valve thread.

Which is defined by ISO 4570 designation "5v2", and is similar to "12-24 UNC"

(edit to add ISO reference)

Comment: So it is! Thank you. You don't happen to know if there any off-the-shelf thread adapters between say M5 and Presta threads?

Comment: no, sorry I don't.

Answer (score 0):

3/16 BSF (3/16in dia 32 turns per inch)

Comment: Do you have any reference to go with this? There is already an accepted answer that differs from what you gave.